# Docker volumes Windows 10

Tags: docker

Сейчас изучаю докер и столкнулся с проблемой: не могу получить доступ к volume. Как я понял они сохраняются в виртуальной машине, где работает докер. Собственно вопрос, как сделать volume в файловой системе.

Использую Windows 10 и Docker Toolbox 19.03.1

Comment: т.е. вы хотите получить достут к файловой системе Windows 10 из контейнера?

Comment: Я хочу получить доступ к volume в файловой системе моей ОС, как это работает в Linux, но в Windows они сохраняются в виртуалке.